# How can I retrieve an object by id in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, say I have an `object_id` for a variable but have forgotten its name, how can I retrieve the object using the id?

I.e. I want the inverse of `some_id = object_id(some_object)`.

Comment: `object_id` is a hash function, which usually means it cannot be easily inverted. Additionally, `some_object` may not be a variable, but an immutable which does not exist later. For example, `object_id(123)` returns a value, but `123` is not a variable and does not exist later in a specific memory location. It might be better to think of another way to solve the problem, perhaps using a Dict and putting your variables in it, with their `object_id(...)` as keys.

Comment: There is an `ObjectIdDict`, which is probably intended for storing by `object_id`. But I think it's pretty undocumented.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @DanGetz says in the comments, `object_id` is a hash function and is designed not to be invertible. @phg is also correct that `ObjectIdDict` is intended precisely for this purpose (it is [documented](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections.html#Base.ObjectIdDict) although not discussed much in the manual):

> `ObjectIdDict([itr])`
>
> `ObjectIdDict()` constructs a hash table where the keys are (always)
>   object identities. Unlike `Dict` it is not parameterized on its key and
>   value type and thus its eltype is always `Pair{Any,Any}`.
>
> See `Dict` for further help.

In other words, it hashes objects by `===` using `object_id` as a hash function. If you have an `ObjectIdDict` and you use the objects you encounter as the keys into it, then you can keep them around and recover those objects later by taking them out of the `ObjectIdDict`.

However, it sounds like you want to do this without the explicit `ObjectIdDict` just by asking which object ever created has a given `object_id`. If so, consider this thought experiment: if every object were always recoverable from its `object_id`, then the system could never discard any object, since it would always be possible for a program to ask for that object by ID. So you would never be able to collect any garbage, and the memory usage of every program would rapidly expand to use all of your RAM and disk space. This is equivalent to having a single global `ObjectIdDict` which you put every object ever created into. So inverting the `object_id` function that way would require never deallocating any objects, which means you'd need unbounded memory.

Even if we had infinite memory, there are deeper problems. What does it mean for an object to exist? In the presence of an optimizing compiler, this question doesn't have a clear-cut answer. It is often the case that an object appears, from the programmer's perspective, to be created and operated on, but in reality – i.e. from the hardware's perspective – it is never created. Consider this function which constructs a complex number and then uses it for a simple computation:

```
julia> function f(y::Real)
           z = Complex(0,y)
           w = 2z*im
           return real(w)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo(123)
-246
```

From the programmer's perspective, this constructs the complex number `z` and then constructs `2z`, then `2z*im`, and finally constructs `real(2z*im)` and returns that value. So all of those values should be inserted into the "Great ObjectIdDict in the Sky". But are they really constructed? Here's the LLVM code for this function applied to an `Int`:

```
julia> @code_llvm foo(123)

define i64 @julia_foo_60833(i64) #0 !dbg !5 {
top:
  %1 = shl i64 %0, 1
  %2 = sub i64 0, %1
  ret i64 %2
}
```

No `Complex` values are constructed at all! Instead, all of the work is inlined and eliminated instead of actually being done. The whole computation boils down to just doubling the argument (by shifting it left one bit) and negating it (by subtracting it from zero). This optimization can be done first and foremost because the intermediate steps have no observable side effects. The compiler knows that there's no way to tell the difference between actually constructing complex values and operating on them and just doing a couple of integer ops – as long as the end result is always the same. Implicit in the idea of a "Great ObjectIdDict in the Sky" is the assumption that all objects that seem to be constructed actually are constructed and inserted into a large, permanent data structure – which is a *massive* side effect. So not only is recovering objects from their IDs incompatible with garbage collection, it's also incompatible with almost every conceivable program optimization.

The only other way one could conceive of inverting `object_id` would be to compute its inverse image on demand instead of saving objects as they are created. That would solve both the memory and optimization problems. Of course, it isn't possible since there are infinitely many possible objects but only a finite number of object IDs. You are vanishingly unlikely to actually encounter two objects with the same ID in a program, but the finiteness of the ID space means that inverting the hash function is impossible *in principle* since the preimage of each ID value contains an infinite number of potential objects.

I've probably refuted the possibility of an inverse `object_id` function far more thoroughly than necessary, but it led to some interesting thought experiments, and I hope it's been helpful – or at least thought provoking. The practical answer is that there is no way to get around explicitly stashing every object you might want to get back later in an `ObjectIdDict`.

Comment: In julia 1.3.1, it is now called `IdDict` and the `object_id` function is now just `objectid`